# react-native TextInput placeholder not visible

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm make simple screen contains only one TextInput with placeholder, but placeholder on displayed. What is wrong?

MyComponent:

```
render() {
  <TextInput
    placeHolder="placeholder"
  />
}
```

index.js:

```
export default () => {
  <MyComponent />
}
```

wrapping TextInput into View don't help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like you misspelled the prop `placeholder` to `placeHolder`. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#placeholder.

Comment: damn, and the issue with this is: On iPhone its works like a charm!

Answer (score 14):

Some like me, may come here forgetting they don't use the default **colors**. Make sure you adjust the [placeholderTextColor](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#placeholdertextcolor) property to **contrast your background color**.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
render() {
  <TextInput
    placeholder="placeholder text"
  />
}
```

like this you can test your component

```
<TextInput
          style={styles.textEdit}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          placeholder="add text here to see in place holder"
        />
```

add this in style

```
textEdit: {
    height: 40, 
    borderColor: 'grey', 
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **Spelling** is wrong

```
placeholder='Sreach' (correct)
```

if not work then you need to check `placeholderTextColor`
some time your background colour and Place holder color are same

Answer (score 1):

Put the attribute placeholderTextColor and set color. The dark mode replace color to white color

Answer (score 0):

Its completely because of wrong spelling of placeholder -> placeHolder.

```js
render() {
  <TextInput
    placeholder="placeholder text"
  />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the "placeholder" Text Case. It should be "small letter" all through

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue With TextInput sometimes it doesnot work
while writing in this way

so you might go with self closing tag
change this above syntax into
self closing tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).